What is the tool of SF icon in Eclipse?
What tool does this SF icon represent on Eclipse? Who can tell me what it is? And how can I use it?

The 'SF' icon the red S and blue F.

I know that this is similar with hover help in Eclipse. But the SF is different with the hover.
I had used google image search, and yandex image search for it, but I still don't get the anwer.I even don't know what is the key word about this staff.
I also searched in youtube, but I didn't find a tutorial about this staff.

In the Outline view S means static and F means final. The red color indicates a private access modifier. Just look at the corresponding line in the source code to verify.

What Abra says. They Java related icons are documented here (in Eclipse go to Help > Help Contents): https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

The image isn't about a tool, it is just a shorthand way of saying public static final
